# Hadoop binary files input error

Tags: java, hadoop

I am getting an error like kkslct gets here:
http://eldadlevy.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/hadoop-binary-files-processing-entroduced-by-image-duplicates-finder/
kkslct solved it but I cannot. Any ideas?

code is:

```
public class BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFileMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, BytesWritable> {

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    String uri = value.toString();
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FSDataInputStream in = null;
    try {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf); ERROR HERE
```

and i get errors like:
ERROR BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFileMapper error, uri: L���2���;fR���ӐT�%2���PHe�Z�әh��T��`���z�/�#��:� null class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with Cause: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 13: L���2���;fR���ӐT�%2���PHe�Z�әh��T��`���z�/�#��:�

It used to work!!

Comment: What is the value of `uri` ? Also, what change made things stop to work ?

Comment: uri is ( I assume) a filename in a directory. In main I set: 
       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(URLEncoder.encode(otherArgs[0],"UTF-8")));
where otherargs[0] is my input folder. It contains a few image files whose names are all fine. I did not change anything!!

Comment: key value pairs are like this:
key: 6125value: ���S
Hadoop sets these values.

Comment: Could you add these details in your question ? It will be much clearer. Could you also tell us how you call this program ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

That was a waste of half a day. I'd forgotten:
 The input is a file contains all the image file as HDFS filenames. For example:

hdfs://localhost:8022/user/elevy/smallArchiveImages/WonderWoman.jpg

http://eldadlevy.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/hadoop-binary-files-processing-entroduced-by-image-duplicates-finder/